# Laravel 5 - Sending notification via Mail shows HTML source instead of HTML

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5, html-email

I'm sending a user - registered confirmation link email after signup.

When i open that mail with my desktop client, all shows very well. When i open that mail with my Android phone client called "Mail" (version 10) it shows the HTML tags and every line of HTML source code instead of rendered HTML.

What am i doing wrong? This is the `toMail` method from the notification:

```
public function toMail() {
    $subject = trans('mail.registration_confirmation');

    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject($subject)
        ->greeting($this->registeredUser->greeting())
        ->line(trans('app.thank_you_for_registering', ['app' => settings('app_name')]))
        ->line(trans('app.confirm_email_on_link_below'))
        ->action(trans('app.confirm_email'), route('register.confirm-email', $this->token))
        ->line(trans('app.confirm_email_call_to_action'))
        ->line("Just another line");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Weird thing. As far as I remember Laravel Notifications byMail are providing a text-version of your mail by default. Have you actually tried to access your mails  with a different mobile e-mail-client? Cant help myself, but it seems like your client is not rendering this propertly... or its a bug in laravel itself.

Comment: Yes @Tschitsch in webmail and desktop client it renders perfectly normal.

Comment: Can you check other emails on your email client on mobile ? I think your mobile email client cannot render html.

Comment: If the content renders fine in other clients, then the issue is with the mobile client you're using, and not Laravel (or the code).